# How to start hangout call with a group of people?

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-api-client, google-hangouts

I have written the following code to start a Hangout Call.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hangout button demo: Inviting people</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <g:hangout render="createhangout">
    </g:hangout>
</body>
</html>
```

**Problem**
How do I add some default members in the Hangout call?

**What I have tried So far**

As per google documentation I have tried the following code snipet

**[Documentation: Basic page with profile and e-mail invites](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#basic_page_with_profile_and_e-mail_invites)**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hangout button demo: Inviting people</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <g:hangout render="createhangout"
        invites="[{ id : 'foo@example.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
    </g:hangout>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is also not working.

Comment: _How do I add some default members in the Hangout call?_......You have just posted markup, where is the logic which failed as you tried?

Comment: @jai I have updated the question and provided the source of the snippets that I found.

Comment: something like this still works?